# Need help and advice in creating a complex relationship in EF 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

After spending so many hours trying to get this to work, I have to admit that I am close to pulling my hair out and want to get some help before that actually happens!

It is very hard to explain the actual application out of context - this is the best example I can think of.

```
public class TheObject{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}

    public int? CategoryNavID {get;set;}
    public virtual Category CategoryNav {get;set;}}

public class CategoryNav{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category {get;set;}}

public class Category{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}

    //The category this is currently in.
    public int CategoryNavID

    //To create sub categories.
    public int? CategoryID {get;set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get;set;}}
```

So, basically, There are a bunch of objects, an object can have as many categories attached, and further to this, a category can have multiple categories attached (to an infinite level).

Again, it is hard to explain out of context - this is not the actual system, but, this is the end goal I am trying to achieve.

Quite frankly, I have been trying for the best part of today to  do this and I am not sure if I am best off with the CategoryNav class, or if there is a better, more straight forward way of doing this.

I just want a solution where I can easily get an object, then go over all categories, then all sub-categories to an infinite level. (At the moment, I am thinking to get the object, then if CategoryNavID is not null, get all the contents, and basically keep doing this over all categories that are returned)

I have got very very close to this, but, I just can't work out the EF FluentAPI/Data Annotations needed in order to have more than one link from Category back to Category nav.

Lastly, I would also like a way if possible to get a `CategoryNav`/ID, and get the original object it belongs to - even if it is the last sub category - 20 down a chain. This is not at all required as I have the logic in place`*` - I am just certain I am not doing it the most efficient way. - Currently thinking it would just be easier to create a "TheObject" FK in Category - I know you are not supposed to repeat data where it isn't needed, but, I think this will be the easiest solution by far.

`*`Currently, I am going a long way round - getting an ID of an category/Nav, checking to see if it exists as a `Object/CategoryNavID`, and if it doesn't, it goes back to category, and searches for any category with it as the categoryID, then get's that category ID and basically keeps looping this action until it finds the top object.

Anyway, All/Any help will be vastly appreciated! Happy to answer any questions.

Comment: I hope this reads well, if it doesn't, I blame it on coding all day and almost getting no where.... Please let me know and I will re-edit/try to tidy up in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you essentially want a many-to-many relationship between your `TheObject` class and `Category` class.  If you think of this in terms of SQL, you would have a `TheObject` table, a `Category` table, and a join table, which you have possibly tried to implemented with your`CategoryNav` class.

Check out these posts for help on creating a many-to-many relationship with EF code first:

- [Creating a Many To Many Mapping Using Code First](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/08/01/creating-a-many-to-many-mapping-using-code-first.aspx)
- [Code First Relationships Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698)
- [Code First EF 4.1 : Building Many to Many Relationship](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship.aspx)

As for the category tree, you would want a one-to-many relationship so that each sub-category only has one parent category, otherwise you are dealing with a graph which will make traversing a lot more complicated.

And lastly, regarding the `CategoryNav` class, I am unsure of what you are trying to achieve with that other than as a link to the categories associated to a `TheObject`.  Wouldn't it be easier just to have a collection of `Category` in your `TheObject` class or is there some other meaning behind `CategoryNav`?